# MYSQL Last inserted row's id without autoincremented Column

Tags: mysql

I Have a Stored Procedure in Mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE REG_LOCATE(IN MDN VARCHAR(50), IN CALLID VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result int(10);
DECLARE transactionId VARCHAR(255);
INSERT INTO  transactions(id, device_number, call_id, creation_time, method_name) VALUES( UUID(), MDN, CALLID, now(), 'MDN_REG_LOCATE');
SELECT id FROM transactions ORDER BY creation_time desc LIMIT 1 INTO transactionId;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have inserted a row in transactions table whose id is being inserted by UUID() of mysql , now how can i get the last inserted id from transactions table inside the same procedure .I have used

```
SELECT id FROM transactions ORDER BY creation_time desc LIMIT 1 INTO transactionId;
```

but it is not giving me the last inserted id .Please help me in this.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result of a call to `UUID()` to a variable first, then use the value of that variable in the `INSERT` statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE REG_LOCATE(IN MDN VARCHAR(50), IN CALLID VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
  DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
  DECLARE result int(10);
  DECLARE transactionId VARCHAR(255);

  SET transactionId := UUID();
  INSERT INTO transactions
    (id, device_number, call_id, creation_time, method_name)
  VALUES
    (transactionId, MDN, CALLID, now(), 'MDN_REG_LOCATE');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```